# Connect Python app with redis using Ecs Ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have 2 dockerfile and I want to link them using Aws-ECS service. I want to link them using Ecs Ec2. What steps I should keep in mind to link the container and what network mode should I used. Lets say I want to expose the container on localhost:5000. I have pushed my docker images to ECR. I want to know what port mapping should I do to python and redis respectively.

Dockerfile python:

```
FROM python:3
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python3 app.py
```

Dockerfile redis:

```
From redis:latest
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Redis and python should be part of the same task definition and then define linking between these two containers.

**links**

The link parameter allows containers to communicate with each other without the need for port mappings. Only supported if the network mode of a task definition is set to bridge. The `name:internalName` construct is analogous to `name:alias` in Docker links. Up to 255 letters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers, hyphens, and underscores are allowed.

[Linking in ECS task defintion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html)

Add below in the python container task definition

```
   "links": [
        "redis"
      ]
```

where `redis` is Redis container name.

```
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 6379,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 6379
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 0,
      "memoryReservation": 400,
      "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/redis",
      "name": "redis"
    },
    {
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 0,
      "memoryReservation": 400,
      "image": "123.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pythonapp",
    "links": [
        "redis"
      ],
      "name": "app"
    }
```

Now you can access Redis container by using `redis:6379` inside app container.

From AWS console

Goto task definition and add container definition in signal task definition

- App contianer
- Redis container

[image]

Now add a link in the container definition of an app

[image]

Comment: I am not using cloudoformation. I am actually using aws console to configure all the changes. Can you help me on that?

Comment: updated. please check

Comment: What network-mode should I select?

Comment: and container ports like i want to host it on localhost:5000 so should I give the port in redis container or python container?

Comment: Bridge net mode should work

Comment: Application port should be publish in pythons container

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the question, Can you tell me if I am pulling the image right? When I go to services and create a service in event section it gives an error  `service flask-redis-service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster.`

Comment: seems lke there is no instance in the cluster