# AWS ECS - dynamic port to be used inside other container ENVs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm running two containers in AWS ECS task. The second one needs to connect to the first one (in bridge mode) - the address of the first needs to be used in the ENV of the the task definition of the second one. Port inside first one are attached dynamically so I cannot hardcode it, then am I able to connect in a dynamic fashion?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to launch both containers in the same task definition and add l[inking between both container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html), then you will able to access the container using `expose port` instead of `publish port`.

So you will able to connect using even if the host port is dynamic as service to service communication will take place using the service name.

```
   "links": [
        "taskb"
      ]
```

Now you will able to access from task A

```
curl http://taskb:CONTAINER_PORT
```

You can check my details answer here that has the same use case.

[Connect Python app with redis using Ecs Ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077970/connect-python-app-with-redis-using-ecs-ec2/63078523#63078523)